# Parse AST and guess if method is async based on its statements and functions calls

Tags: php, loops, nested-loops, abstract-syntax-tree, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to implement a library which provides [NodeVisitor](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/1.x/doc/2_Usage_of_basic_components.markdown#node-traversation) (or some other kind of loop) that given a set of functions that are assumed as async (think as them would be link in nodejs) like mysql_query, fwrite, fopen, etc... does:

Create a registry (this is what I've already done) that loops in each function/classmethod and:

- Register the namespace, class, method or function of the classmethod/function
- Registers all the functions/classmethods used by this functions
- Registers all functions/classmethods that uses this function.

and then (this is what my question is about) loop the AST and marks every function/class method as:

- **Sync** by default, all methods are marked as sync, this occurs when all function call inside is sync, like text or array manipulation (str_replace, array_shift, etc..)
- **Maybe async** if in this state, it could be switched to sync or async manually or either by the code itself in a second moment. This involves function with method calls on a instance of an unknown type.
- **Async** if in this state, it could not be reverted back. This means that the function/classmethod includes function/classmethods calls that are strictly defined as async from the user or either calls a function marked as async in the registry by the code itselfs.

My question is: What would be an efficient way to do the loop to assign if sync, async o maybe to the function? The problem is that a function state depends on other function state, that may be even in circular dependency, so if I change a function to async all the functions that uses it should be changed to async, but not only the first parent; all the parents up to the root program. If possible, I would like to avoid while loops! :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hey, any updates on this? Did you manage to solve it? Could you share a link to your project? I'm very interested in AST in PHP-related projects.